# Can Valorous be my starting 16 trait?

Tags: character-creation, pendragon

Can Valorous be my starting 16 trait in Pendragon 5th edition?

In the Pendragon book fifth edition it states:

> The Valorous trait always begins at a value of 15, reflecting your
>   character’s martial training.

but then goes on to say

> 3. Assign Your “Famous Trait”: You may assign a value of 16 to any
>      one trait, including those on the right side of each binary, such as
>      Worldly or Reckless, if you desire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the three games I played, it was allowed.

The rule for Valorous just means you don't use the normal mechanism to start that trait off.